# Wordpress tables and aliases?

Tags: mysql

I have imported some tables from my online wordpress database to my local to work on.

However now I am getting some weird sql errors that I don't get online.

I can see that the code of the plugin I am working on has some references (aliases?) that don't appear to reference anything that I see when I do a search:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT re.*
                                    FROM ' . EVENT_ESPRESSO_RECURRENCE_TABLE . ' re
                                    INNER JOIN ' . EVENTS_DETAIL_TABLE . ' ed
                                    ON re.recurrence_id = ed.recurrence_id
                                    WHERE re.recurrence_id = ' . $recurrence_id .
                        ' ORDER BY ed.start_date ASC
                                    LIMIT 1', ARRAY_A );
```

What is table 're'? In re.recurrence_id?

Comment: I can't see how this question serves any use to the community here, sorry voting to close (note: the constants refer to the table names, find them and you'll find what you're looking for).

Comment: By constants do you mean what's written in caps or the part labelled 're'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

're' is the alias you give to EVENT_ESPRESSO_RECURRENCE_TABLE.

The error you're seeing is probably because the EVENT_ESPRESSO_RECURRENCE_TABLE constant isn't defined.

Do a `var_dump( $wpdb->last_query )` just below that code to see the final SQL statement.